# Webpack Dev Server Proxy with Dynamic URL

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have this URL: `sample/company/1231/invoices/download/123`

This is my Webpack Dev Server configuration

```
devServer: {
   proxy: {
     '/sample/company' : {
       target: envConfig.WEBPACK_DEVSERVER_PROXY,
       ws: true,
       changeOrigin: true,
     }
   }
}
```

My problem with this is that all URLs that has a `/sample/company` gets affected. I only wanted to take the rule into effect when it has URL `sample/company/1231/invoices/download/123`.

The `123` are dynamic, these are IDs.

I'm new to this so any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pathRewrite` to create your own rewrite function. I did not test it but it must be something like this:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/sample/company' : {
      target: envConfig.WEBPACK_DEVSERVER_PROXY,
      ws: true,
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: function(path, req){
        var arrMatches = path.match(/\/sample\/company\/(.+)\/invoices\/download\/(.+)/);
        if(arrMatches){
          // arrMatches[0] > fullmatch
          // arrMatches[1] > group 1
          // arrMatches[2] > group 2
          return 'my/new/path/' + arrMatches[1] + '/' + arrMatches[2] + '/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/pathRewrite.md#custom-rewrite-function)